# What does (-’string’.length) do in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time following this concept.  The point of the function is for it to take 2 parameters and test if the `target` parameter is the end of the `str` parameter.

So `end('Sebastion', 'ion')` would return `true` and `end('Sebastion', 'eon')` would return `false`

I found this solution and don't understand what the `-target.length` is doing and how matching that to target is testing the parameters.

I'm fairly new to JavaScript so if someone has any insight on how this is working that would be great.

```
function end(str, target) {
  return (str.substr(-target.length) === target);
}
```

Comment: New or not, reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) is always useful.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you read the doc?

Comment: I read the documentation or else I wouldn't have come to overflow for a general "what does this do?" question because of comments like yours.  I just still didn't understand what it was doing after reading explanations of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's evaluate `str.substr(-target.length)`.

Following the [rules of precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), we need to evaluate `-target.length` first.

Again following the rules of precedence, we evaluate `target.length` first.  We do this because "Member Access" is near the top of the precedence table.  This evaluates to `3` in your example.

Negate that, to get `-3`.

Okay, so now we need to evaluate the result of `str.substr(-3)`:

The JavaScript `substr` function has this in this [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

> start: Location at which to begin extracting characters. If a negative number is given, it is treated as strLength + start where strLength is the length of the string (for example, if start is -3 it is treated as strLength - 3.)
>
> If start is negative, substr() uses it as a character index from the end of the string. If start is negative and abs(start) is larger than the length of the string, substr() uses 0 as the start index. Note: the described handling of negative values of the start argument is not supported by Microsoft JScript.

So it takes the final 3 characters of the source string.

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you.